# HTML images wont appear on my local host. Is my path correct?

Tags: html, css

My code is as follows:

```
<img src="C:\Users\Brad\Desktop\Root Folder\img\Spidey.jpg" alt="">
```

File structure:

```
 Root Folder
 |_ src
    |_ index.html
    |_ img
       |_ Spidey.jpg
```

The image folder is within the same root folder that hold all of my other HTML files. Any suggestions? When I reload it, the broken image icon appears. In the code, I have used your suggestions img src="../img/Spidey.jpg" as well as img src="/img/Spidey.jpg" alt"" with no results other than the broken image Icon.

Comment: i think you forgot to add your code

Comment: `<img src="img/Spidey.jpg">`

Comment: How are you running your html code? localhost:[port]/index.html? Or are you opening it directly. You should get used to using relative paths like "./img/Spidey.jpg" assuming your index.html is under `Root Folder`

Answer (score 0):

no need to set absolute path for image just set relative path:

Try this:

```
<img src="../img/Spidey.jpg" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<img src="../img/Spidey.jpg" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just try a relative path from your HTML file to your image:

```
<img src="../img/Spidey.jpg" alt="" />
```

This is easier than an absolute path, and means the page will still work if it's online.

Answer (score 0):

your image tag is `<img src="C:\Users\Brad\Desktop\Root Folder\img\Spidey.jpg" alt="">`

but your structure shows that between root folder and img you also have a src folder

```
Root Folder
 |_ src
    |_ index.html
    |_ img
```

so you should be using **/src/img/Spidey.jpg**